# Why does jshint not recognize an assignment as an expression?

Tags: javascript, jshint

How do I need to modify these lines to make jshint happy?

An assignment is an expression. Why doesn't jshint understand this? Obviously the interpreter does.

```
Line 572: while(bookmark_element=bookmark_list[iterator++])

Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.


Line 582: while(bookmark_element=bookmark_list[iterator++])

Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.


Line 623: while(element_iterator=element_iterator.nextSibling)

Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you really want to listen to JSHint, convert the expression to a boolean by:

```
while (!!(bookmark_element=bookmark_list[iterator++]))

! means: Something that evaluates to true is converted to false,
         something that evaluates to false is converted to true.
```

So, `!!` means: Convert something to the conditional representation.

Comment: easiest..so i went with this.

Comment: does javascipt have a cast to bool of sorts...someting more direct?

Comment: @stack.user.0 More direct than `!!`? That's about as direct as it gets: JavaScript has truthy/falsy, if you want an actual boolean, `!!` is your easiest bet.

Comment: You actually don't need to cast to boolean here. The addition of the extra parenthesis around the assignment is enough for jshint to recognize it as an expression. So in the answer above, you can remove the !! and the warning is still silenced

Answer (score 19):

```
/*jshint boss:true */
```

Experiment with the [options](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/).

Answer (score 13):

I'm sure that jshint understands the expression fine, it is just that most people who write `if (a = b)` actually meant `if (a == b)` and so this generates a warning.

Since your code is what you intended you could add an explicit test:

```
while ((element_iterator = element_iterator.nextSibling) !== null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two ways to solve the reported error, according to [JSHint docs](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#boss).

1. Add `/*jshint boss:true */` before conditional statement
2. Wrap statement in extra parentheses, i.e.  `while ((element_iterator = element_iterator.nextSibling)) {...}`

Personally, I think surrounding with extra parentheses is best practice since it keeps the error check but still makes good sense code-wise. Adding the `!!` before does actually nothing but convert the expression to true/false back and forth two extra times.

Comment: However, it's worth noting that the warning about "variable shadowing", especially in the case of the for loop.
 reference: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#shadow

Answer (score 0):

It is an expression, and you can modify it to work with JSHint (although it's not nice) like so:

```
while(element_iterator.nextSibling) {
    element_iterator = element_iterator.nextSibling;
```

For your last example. However, you don't need to do this. JSHint is only a tool to help you improve coding habits and correct mistakes, but given that what you have is clear, concise, and (in my opinion) the best way of doing it - just ignore those messages.

Answer (score 0):

jshint can't tell if you really meant to make an assignment in the condition block, or if that was really supposed to be a comparison. The concern would be that other humans might have the same doubt.

In the case of an iterator, I think you're okay.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because I had a trailing comma in a declaration preceding the function:

```
this.foo = "bar",   // <- Error was here

this.myfunc = function() {
   ...   // <- Error reported on this line
};
```

<sub>(It was hard to find, but reinforces my opinion that linters are usually right, it's my code that's wrong.  If I had disabled the warnings globally - or even in that spot - the bug still would have been present.`</lecture>`)</sub>

Comment: This is not the same warning as in this question. This is [W030](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/78b79c099fc490d93cd7aef599a1528761e9498d/src/messages.js#L112) and the question talks about [W084](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/78b79c099fc490d93cd7aef599a1528761e9498d/src/messages.js#L171). While similar, this is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `/* jshint expr: true */` comment in your Javascript file, it will not show warning anymore.