# Is there a reason to not assign a variable in the while block declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever I do something like this...

```
var obj;

while (obj = doSomething()) {
  // something with obj
}
```

JSHint tells me `warning  84| Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.`. However, doing `obj = doSomething()` returns the value that `doSomething()` returns during assignment, so it makes sense to write a while loop in this fashion.

Is there a specific reason that JSHint warns me, and more importantly, are there reasons to not do this? Or can I tell JSHint to ignore those lines for that specific warning?

Comment: You can also use `for (var obj = doSomething(); obj; obj = doSomething())`

Comment: @Bergi At first glance that looks like quite a wacky for-loop, using `while` seems easier to read to me.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108184/why-does-jshint-not-recognize-an-assignment-as-an-expression. By the way, this is not a "while block *declaration*", but rather a "while [block] *condition*".

Comment: @Bergi That's pretty interesting -- wouldn't have thought to use a for loop in that way though.

Comment: @torazaburo I don't think you understood my question when you say it's as a duplicate of that question, because it and this question are discussing similar but distinct things. That, or you just decided to find a question that's vaguely similar and say it's a possible duplicate...

Comment: Personally, I think it's an exact duplicate, but we'll let the community decide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That warning is to make sure that you have not mistyped `=` instead of `==` or `===`.

Instead, you can get the boolean value of the evaluated result, like this

```
while (!!(obj = doSomething())) {
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I wish I could just use my original syntax without triggering an error but this is a good compromise without using JSHint specific comments.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `!!`; the extra set of parentheses are enough to shut jshint up.

Answer (score -2):

The single `=` assigns value and is not a comparison operator. Use the below:

```
while (obj == doSomething()) {
  // something with obj
}
```

Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: It appears you don't understand the question, the OP knows very well the difference. They are purposely using `=`.

Comment: Oh ok.. Wouldn't that result in an infinite loop then? (I am assuming the other case would assign the value and evaluate the boolean as true always)

Comment: Actually, this answer is a perfect example of why it's a bad idea - it could be misinterpreted as unintentional.

Comment: @Playmaker: Not if a) there is a `break` statement somewhere in the body or b) `doSomething()` returns a different value for each call and probably `null` when there are no more results.

Comment: @Playmaker The result of `doSomething` could very well change from iteration to iteration and is reevaluated everytime, so this does not need to be an infinte loop.

Comment: Hmm.. a (somewhat) explicit break would be required..Thanks!

Comment: The while loop can modify some values used in the doSomething method. Whilst the intention is not obvious, the loop can or cannot end.

Comment: For practical context, I'm using this kind of loop specifically for reading binary buffers where the result of the `doSomething()` function will either return data (and assign to `obj`) or return nothing and end the loop.

Comment: Oh. That explains it. Maybe even I'll use it sometime in the future :D

Comment: @slebetman I don't agree with you. Doing this is not a bad idea, would you say when people do: `while($row = $mysqli->query($query))` in PHP is a bad idea? No, it's a convenient one. This *method* has it places.